# Is it possible to auto bind an object passed into a Node route to an Angular $scope object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

This is a MEAN stack (MongoDB, Express, Angular, and Node), using Jade as the template engine.

This form is creating users perfectly:

```
extends layout

block content
    div(ng-controller="Controller")
        .row
            .col-md-6
                .panel.panel-default
                    .panel-heading
                        h3.panel-title User Form
                        .actions.pull-right
                            | <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i><i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    .panel-body
                        form(role="form" novalidate class="user-form")
                            .form-group
                                label First Name
                                input(type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Eddard" ng-model="user.firstname")
                            .form-group
                                label Last Name
                                input(type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Stark" ng-model="user.lastname")
                            .form-group
                                label Email
                                input(type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="estark@winteriscoming.net" ng-model="user.email")
                            .form-group
                                label Password
                                input(type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="super-secret-password" ng-model="user.password")
                            button(ng-click="reset()" class="btn btn-secondary") Reset
                            | &nbsp;
                            button(ng-click="update(user)" class="btn btn-primary") Save
            .col-md-6
                pre
                    | form = {{ user | json }}
                pre
                    | master = {{ master | json }}
    script. 
        function Controller($scope, $http) {
            $scope.master = {};
            $scope.update = function(user) {
                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/users/create',
                    data: user,
                }).success(function(response) { $scope.master = angular.copy(response); }) ;

            };

            $scope.reset = function() {
                $scope.user = angular.copy($scope.master);
            };

            $scope.reset();
        }
```

But I would like to use the same form to edit users, as well as create them. I have the routes setup like this:

```
exports.create_user = function(req, res) {
    res.render('user-form', {title: 'Create User'});
};

exports.user = function(req, res) {
    User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
        res.render('user-form', {title: 'Edit User', user: user});
    });
};
```

How can I make the `user` passed back to the `exports.user` route bind to the user object being used by Angular?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to build an api and send json back, because what you're doing is rendering the user-form form again.  So try something like this:

```
User.findById(req.params.id, function(err, user) {
  res.send(user);
});
```

If you want to maintain a single page app, it's more about creating an API versus individual jade templates.

Comment: Okay cool, how would I tie that into my user-form template? Like.. what would call the API?